# To change color only tapped image color of UICollectionView in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I've created image in NSArray as follow in viewDidLoad.

```
menuImgs = @[@"image1", @"image2", @"image3", @"image4"];
```

And apply above images in UICollectionView as follow.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *iconImg = [UIImage imageNamed:menuImgs[arrayCountChecker]];
    UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:menuImgs[arrayCountChecker]]];
    cellImage.frame = CGRectMake(cellWidth/2-iconImg.size.width,cellHeight/2-iconImg.size.height, iconImg.size.width, iconImg.size.height);
    [cell addSubview:cellImage];

    return cell;
}
```

What I want is I want to change image color when tapped on specific UICollectionViewCell in this function.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: you can set cell.selectedBackgroundView property of cell.

Comment: @vivek complete example?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change background color of selected cell then use cell.selectedBackgroundView otherwise,

intialize one array and store selected index in that array. And when collectionview load data check index from array and change image color according. When someone select new cell remove old index from array and store new and and reload colloectionview. Here is code example.

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
CollectionViewCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.lblFilter.text   = filterTitles[indexPath.row];
cell.imgvFilter.image = filterImages[indexPath.row];

if([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath])
{
    cell.imgvFilter.superview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightBlue].CGColor;

    cell.lblFilter.textColor = [UIColor lightBlue];
}
else
{
    cell.lblFilter.textColor = [UIColor textGray];

    cell.imgvFilter.superview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor borderGray].CGColor;
}

return cell;
}



- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[collvFilter scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];

if (![indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathToReload = selectedIndexPath;

    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [collvFilter reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToReload, indexPath]];
}
 }
```